# Increment field in Select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have some data which i dont have a group statement in, and would not like to have a group statement in.
But i would like to have an increment field so i can can do a reporting services zebra table.

So, how do i turn this data:

```
region    country     office    somedata     someotherdata
EUROPE    Austria     Vienna    12           2
ASIA      India       Delhi     22           4
```

Into

```
region    country     office    somedata     someotherdata     IncField
EUROPE    Austria     Vienna    12           2                 1
ASIA      India       Delhi     22           4                 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try using the

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeData) AS IncField
, *
FROM TableName
```

[Edit] Works with Sql Server 2005 and 2008

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL Server 2005` and above:

```
SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY someotherdata) AS IncField
FROM    mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert your data into a temp table, which has an additional field (IDENTITY) as an incremental counter.